# How can I convert this SQL query to JOINs?

Tags: sql, join

I need to convert this type of query with joins but I don't have any idea about this, can someone explain this to me?

```
select 
    company.*, 
    (select metadatavalues.Value 
     from MetaDataValues metadatavalues, MetaData metadata 
     where metadata.Id = metadatavalues.MetaDataId 
       and metadata.[Order] = 1 
       and metadatavalues.Active = 1 
       and metadatavalues.CompanyId = company.Id) as Metadata1, 
    (select metadatavalues.Value  
     from MetaDataValues metadatavalues, MetaData metadata
     where metadata.Id = metadatavalues.MetaDataId 
       and metadata.[Order] = 2 
       and metadatavalues.Active = 1 
       and metadatavalues.CompanyId = company.Id) as Metadata2,
    (select metadatavalues.Value  
     from MetaDataValues metadatavalues, MetaData metadata
     where metadata.Id = metadatavalues.MetaDataId 
       and metadata.[Order] = 3 
       and metadatavalues.Active = 1 
       and metadatavalues.CompanyId = company.Id) as Metadata3,
    (select metadatavalues.Value  
     from MetaDataValues metadatavalues, MetaData metadata
     where metadata.Id = metadatavalues.MetaDataId 
       and metadata.[Order] = 4 
       and metadatavalues.Active = 1 
       and metadatavalues.CompanyId = company.Id) as Metadata4,
    (select metadatavalues.Value  
     from MetaDataValues metadatavalues, MetaData metadata
     where metadata.Id = metadatavalues.MetaDataId 
       and metadata.[Order] = 5 
       and metadatavalues.Active = 1 
       and metadatavalues.CompanyId = company.Id) as Metadata5
from 
    Company company;
```

The schema is this:

[image]

Thanks you so much!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please provide database schema.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Linking to pictures (while a picture provides more than 1000 words) makes this question less useful in the future as the picture of the link can (and often will) get lost. Just for the future.

Comment: I use SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is converting this:

```
(select metadatavalues.Value 
     from MetaDataValues metadatavalues, MetaData metadata 
     where metadata.Id = metadatavalues.MetaDataId 
       and metadata.[Order] = 1 
       and metadatavalues.Active = 1 
       and metadatavalues.CompanyId = company.Id) as Metadata1,
```

to this - using a **proper** `JOIN` operator instead of comma-separated tables in the `FROM` clause:

```
(select metadatavalues.Value 
 from MetaDataValues mv
 inner join MetaData metadata md on mv.MetaDataId = md.Id
 where md.[Order] = 1 
   and mv.Active = 1 
   and mv.CompanyId = company.Id) as Metadata1,
```

Basically, you use `inner join` between the two tables (instead of just a comma in the `from` clause), and you take the first condition in your previous `where` clause and this is your **join condition** that you specify after the `inner join`. Do this for all five subqueries.

Comment: How do you get the information from company.Id if you don't mention this table?

Comment: @StellaEsparza: the `company` table is mentioned in the outer scope (the outer `SELECT`)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to be something like this, sub-selects make the query run row by row so it won't scale very well to large tables. I think you need left joins too because your original query will return every record from the company table:

```
SELECT company.*
    , MetaDataValues1.Value as Metadata1
    , MetaDataValues2.Value as Metadata2
    , MetaDataValues3.Value as Metadata3
    , MetaDataValues4.Value as Metadata4
    , MetaDataValues5.Value as Metadata5
from Company company

LEFT JOIN MetaDataValues MetaDataValues1
ON metadatavalues1.CompanyId = company.Id
LEFT JOIN MetaData Metadata1
ON Metadata1.Id = MetaDataValues1.MetaDataId 
and Metadata1.[Order] = 1 
and MetaDataValues1.Active = 1

LEFT JOIN MetaDataValues MetaDataValues2
ON metadatavalues2.CompanyId = company.Id
LEFT JOIN MetaData Metadata2
ON Metadata2.Id = MetaDataValues2.MetaDataId 
and Metadata2.[Order] = 2 
and MetaDataValues2.Active = 1

LEFT JOIN MetaDataValues MetaDataValues3
ON metadatavalues3.CompanyId = company.Id
LEFT JOIN MetaData Metadata3
ON Metadata3.Id = MetaDataValues2.MetaDataId 
and Metadata3.[Order] = 3 
and MetaDataValues3.Active = 1

LEFT JOIN MetaDataValues MetaDataValues4
ON metadatavalues4.CompanyId = company.Id
LEFT JOIN MetaData Metadata4
ON Metadata4.Id = MetaDataValues4.MetaDataId 
and Metadata4.[Order] = 4 
and MetaDataValues4.Active = 1
    
LEFT JOIN MetaDataValues MetaDataValues5
ON metadatavalues5.CompanyId = company.Id
LEFT JOIN MetaData Metadata5
ON Metadata5.Id = MetaDataValues5.MetaDataId 
and Metadata5.[Order] = 5 
and MetaDataValues5.Active = 1
```